# Python - comma separated slices not working

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, slice

I've seen a lot of people use commas when they slice a multidimensional list. For example:

```py
a = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
print(a[0:1, 2:4])
```

But for some reason it doesn't work for me. It raises an exception:

```py
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

How do I fix it???

Comment: what is your expected output in this case?

Comment: @balderman That would be [2, 3]

Comment: try `print(a[0][2:4])`

Comment: @balderman But say the dimensions are arbitrary and I don't know how many slices I have to perform.

Comment: regular python list don't support this advance type of slicing, you either need do it by parts as @balderman show, make your own class or subclass of list that support it or simply use a library that support it such as numpy

Comment: @Copperfield Got it.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible when you use numpy arrays, not python's inbuilt lists.
Example:

```
a = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
print(a[0,1]) # returns an error
b = np.array(a)
print(b[0,1]) # returns 1
```

Similarly, you can also use slices.

Comment: Other packages allow this type of indexing also.

Comment: I wanted to assert it would not be possible with python's inbuilt lists

Comment: Right, its the wording that its only available in numpy that is concerning.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `a` is really just a nested list, rather than a true *matrix*.
Once you convert it to a `numpy` array, accessing those slices will start to work.

e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
print(a[0:1, 2:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects decide for themselves how they can be indexed. When python sees `a[0:1, 2:4]` it starts by creating slice object for the `:` separated values and then combines them into a tuple: `(slice(0, 1, None), slice(2, 4, None))`. That tuple is passed to the object's `__getitem__`: `a[(slice(0, 1, None), slice(2, 4, None))]`. Pass that tuple to `list.__getitem__` and its lost - it doesn't recognize that type of indexing. Put it in a pandas dataframe and use its "iloc" index based indexing, and it works.

```
>>> a = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> a[0:1, 2:4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(a)
>>> df.iloc[0:1, 2:4]
   2  3
0  2  3
```

There are other packages like `pandas` that push the envelope on what indexing means. So to answer your question, it depends on what type of object you are talking about. And different objects are free to interpret the slicing differently.

Comment: Ok then. I'll make a `MultiDimSlicer` class to do this...

Comment: @RudraPatel - certainly doable. You could also write a function `def slicer(my_list, *slices)` that does it. When you implement your class, especially if it inherits from the builtin `list` class, it will likely need more code that the single-purose function.

Answer (score 0):

I made a `MultiDimSlicer` class for this slicing, like you answered.

```py
class MultiDimSlicer:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)
    def __getitem__(self, keys):
        return eval("self.data" + self.__slicestr(keys))
    def __setitem__(self, keys, value):
        exec("self.data" + self.__slicestr(keys) + " = " + str(value))
    def __slicestr(self, keys):
        slice_str = ""
        if isinstance(keys[0], itertypes):
            good_keys = keys[0]
        else:
            good_keys = keys
        for key in good_keys:
            slice_str += "[" + str(key) + "]"
        return slice_str
    reuse = __init__
```